# How to get value by key from map, no matter - key is string or atom?

Tags: elixir

Is there any native elixir method which allows me to get value by key from map, no matter key is atom or string? Like:

```
a = %{ k: 1 }
b = %{ "k" => 1 }

pure_elixir_method(a, :k) => 1 
pure_elixir_method(b, :k) => 1
```

Comment: Pretty sure there isn't.

Comment: Why not just use `Map.get(map, to_string key)`? `to_string` behaves like the identity function when given a string.

Comment: What do you expect this method to return for `%{k: 1, "k" => 2}`?

Comment: @helios35 because your proposal won’t work for `%{k: 1}`?

Comment: @mudasobwa I though about this rare situation, but don't know what to answer here =(

Comment: @asiniy that’s a perfect explanation on why such a method can’t exist.

Comment: @mudasobwa xDDD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the desired behaviour might be achieved with defining the specific [protocol](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Kernel.html#defprotocol/2):

```
defprotocol IndifferentAccess do
  def get(data, key)
end

defimpl IndifferentAccess, for: Map do
  def get(data, key) when is_binary(key) do
    case Map.fetch(data, key) do
      {:ok, value} -> value
      :error ->
        case Map.fetch(data, String.to_atom(key)) do
          {:ok, value} -> value
          :error -> :error
        end
      end
    end
  end
  def get(data, key) when is_atom(key) do
    case Map.fetch(data, key) do
      {:ok, value} -> value
      :error -> get(data, Atom.to_string(key))
    end
  end
end

a = %{ k: 1 }
b = %{ "k" => 1 }
a |> IndifferentAccess.get(:k)
#⇒ 1
b |> IndifferentAccess.get(:k)
#⇒ 1
```

But I won’t do that.

Answer (score 5):

**There isn't one.**

But you can write your own wrapper method to do that:

```ex
defmodule MyMap do
  def get(map, key) when is_atom(key) do
    Map.get(map, key) || Map.get(map, to_string(key))
  end
end
```

Use it like this:

```ex
map = %{:a => 1, "b" => 2}

MyMap.get(map, :a)     # => 1
MyMap.get(map, :b)     # => 2
```

---

<sup>1. Just because you can, doesn't mean you should. `%{k: 1, "k" => 2}` is an excellent example why you shouldn't do this (especially for data you don't know about).</sup>

<sup>2. This method only works for `atom` key arguments, you can modify it so it accepts both atom and string arguments: `MyMap.get(map, "a")  # => 1`</sup>

<sup>3. If you really like getting map values using atoms, consider symbolizing keys of your map at the start. See my [`ExUtils.Map.symbolize_keys/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/ex_utils/ExUtils.Map.html#atomize_keys/2). If you want to implement it yourself, you can [get the code here](https://github.com/sheharyarn/ex_utils/blob/master/lib/ex_utils/map.ex#L35-L39).</sup>